# How should I understand the word 'bum' in this title

Tags: word-meaning

There's a popular YouTube channel called **LittleBabyBum**. What's 'bum' here? Is it like, buttocks? Or a homeless person? I've found out that the couple who run the channel nicknamed their kid like that. Is it considered an ok nickname for a child?

Comment: Not familiar with the channel, but odds are, BabyBum is a reference to buttocks, not to an infant who is homeless. But on the internet, you never know.  It would be a jocular and insensitive reference to homelessness, if so.

Comment: You can name anything you like whatever you like. Many names of things like blogs or YouTube channels are intended to be double entendres. Your guess is as good as ours as to what this couple intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot tell those people's intent. However:

"Bum" is occasionally used as a cute/silly diminutive for babies. "[Baby's name]-bum" is something I've heard from my parents. It's baby talk.

I cannot find any sources for this, so it is probably regional. Perhaps it is untrue and my parents made it up (probable). I am from Australia and New Zealand.

I think the word comes from "Bumpkin".

> **bumpkin** (n.) "awkward country fellow," 1560s, probably from Middle Dutch bommekijn "little barrel," diminutive of boom "tree" (see beam (n.)). Apparently, though itself Dutch, it began as a derogatory reference to Dutch people as short and dumpy.
>
> http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bumpkin

**Bumpkin** refers to a baby in a version of the "Baby Bunting" nursery rhyme:

> "Bye, baby bumpkin, where's Tony Lumpkin?
>
> My lady's on her death-bed, with eating half a pumpkin."
>
> http://www.gutenberg.org/files/24065/24065-h/24065-h.htm original publish date 1899

It is also used in this UK flyer to describe a baby class: http://www.richmond.gov.uk/hamccautumn2012.pdf